# Expanding variables in l3regex to check match

Tags: expansion, expl3, csv

With the following code I want to match any word *this_example* and to replace it with ***example***this. I'm using the values extracted from the A column of a csv file. My problem is that `\demo{\Fst}` does not match any \Fst value, while `\demo{this_example}` seems to work. Is there a way to expand the values within `\Fst` in order to pass to l3regex not the command but the value? Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{datatool,filecontents,tabularx,booktabs}
\DTLloaddb[keys={A,B}]{termlog}{my.csv}
\DTLsort{A=ascending}{termlog}

\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{l3regex}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_demo_tl
\cs_new:Npn \demo #1 {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_demo_tl {#1}
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { ([^\d]+)\_([^\d]+) } {  \cB\{\c{textbf}\cB\{\2\cE\}\cE\}\1 } \l_demo_tl
    \tl_use:N \l_demo_tl
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}      
\begin{longtable}{llllll}
  \toprule
  \textbf{Col1} & \textbf{Col2} \\
  \midrule
  \DTLforeach{termlog}{%
    \Fst=A,\Snd=B}{%
    \demo{\Fst} & \textit{\Snd}  \\
  }
  \\[-\normalbaselineskip] \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

This is an example of CSV file:

```
this_is,some
text_to,fold
or,not
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the `.csv` file you're using?

Comment: Sure, I've edited the post.

Comment: Replace `\tl_set:Nn` by `\tl_set:Nx`?

Comment: It worked. I'm a l3regex noob. What is the difference? Thanks

Comment: No relation with `l3regex`.  `\tl_set:Nn` means "in this variable, store exactly what follows", whereas `\tl_set:Nx` first e**x**pands the second argument before storing it.  A variant which egreg uses is `V`-type expansion which means "unpack the **v**ariable", so for instance you could have used `\tl_set:NV` (I just read the question a bit too fast).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use `\tl_set:Nx` instead of `\tl_set:Nn` so the argument to `\demo` is fully expanded. However, I'm not very keen on this approach, because full expansion might be dangerous if the first column contains macros.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
this_is,some
text_to,fold
or,not
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{datatool,filecontents,tabularx,booktabs}
\DTLloaddb[keys={A,B},noheader]{termlog}{\jobname.csv}
\DTLsort{A=ascending}{termlog}

\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\demo{sm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   { \jackb_demo:V #2 }
   { \jackb_demo:n {#2} }
 }

\tl_new:N \l_jackb_demo_tl
\cs_new:Npn \jackb_demo:n #1
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_jackb_demo_tl {#1}
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { ([^\d]+)\_([^\d]+) } {  \cB\{\c{textbf}\cB\{\2\cE\}\cE\}\1 } \l_jackb_demo_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_jackb_demo_tl
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \jackb_demo:n { V }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}      
\begin{longtable}{llllll}
  \toprule
  \textbf{Col1} & \textbf{Col2} \\
  \midrule
  \DTLforeach{termlog}{%
    \Fst=A,\Snd=B}{%
    \demo*{\Fst} & \textit{\Snd}  \\
  }
  \\[-\normalbaselineskip] \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

You can use `\demo` also elsewhere with the non star form. If you only need it in `DTLforeach`, just replace the `\NewDocumentCommand` with

```
\NewDocumentCommand\demo{m}
 {
  \jackb_demo:V #1
 }
```

and replace `\demo*` with `\demo`.

[image]