# Expand \date with l3regex

Tags: expansion, expl3, latex3, xparse, l3regex

I'm trying to extract the current year from the `\date` command using `l3regex` to match 4 consecutive numbers from whatever is passed to `\date{ ... }`. However, I also want to get the year value if one passes in `\today`.

My solution below works fine when a date is entered manually.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{expl3, xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N  \g_year_seq % Sequence to store the match from regex
\tl_new:N   \g_year_tl  % Token list to store the year
\tl_new:N   \g_date_tl  % Token list to store the full date

%% Re-define \date to store value in a tokenlist
\RenewDocumentCommand\date{ m }     
{
    \tl_gset:Nn \g_date_tl {#1}
    \regex_extract_all:nnN {(\d{4})} {#1} \g_year_seq
    \tl_gset:Nn \g_year_tl {\seq_item:Nn \g_year_seq {1}}
}

\NewDocumentCommand\printdate{ }
{
    The~date~is:~\g_date_tl \par
    The~year~is:~\g_year_tl
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

%% Set the date
% \date{August, 2017} %% Works like a charm
% \date{\today} %% Doesnt work

\begin{document}
\printdate
\end{document}
```

But when `\today` is passed, nothing is matched, presumably because `\regex_extract_all:nnN` does nothing with the second parameter. Looking to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342508/expanding-variables-in-l3regex-to-check-match) question and [this](http://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/source3.pdf) source, I would think that changing `\regex_extract_all:nnN` to `\regex_extract_all:nVN`or `\regex_extract_all:nxN` would expand `\today`, but using it produces the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\date code ..._date_tl {#1}\regex_extract_all:nVN
                                                  {(\d {4})}#1\g_year_seq \t...
l.28 \date{\today}
                   %% Doesnt work
```

How can I parse the value of `\g_date_tl` to get the year if `\today` is used?

Comment: Note that your variable names should use a distinctive prefix e.g. `\g_hatsvi_year_seq` rather than `\g_year_seq`, which is much more likely to cause trouble. Also, `xparse` creation commands should wrap internal functions and just provide a user interface, but not really do anything themselves.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to fully expand `\today`, otherwise there will be literally `\today` inside that string.  Therefore you have to generate the necessary variant for `\regex_extract_all:nnN`.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{expl3, xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N  \g_year_seq % Sequence to store the match from regex
\tl_new:N   \g_year_tl  % Token list to store the year
\tl_new:N   \g_date_tl  % Token list to store the full date

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_extract_all:nnN { nx }

%% Re-define \date to store value in a tokenlist
\RenewDocumentCommand\date{ m }     
{
    \tl_gset:Nx \g_date_tl {#1}
    \regex_extract_all:nxN {(\d{4})} {#1} \g_year_seq
    \tl_gset:Nn \g_year_tl {\seq_item:Nn \g_year_seq {1}}
}

\NewDocumentCommand\printdate{ }
{
    The~date~is:~\g_date_tl \par
    The~year~is:~\g_year_tl
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

%% Set the date
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\printdate
\end{document}
```